# Flutter Invalid locale on xenial

Tags: ubuntu, dart, flutter

Trying to get flutter to work on Ubuntu xenial, it crashes with doctor command or trying to run a project...

### command

flutter --no-color config --machine

### exception

> ArgumentError: Invalid argument(s): Invalid locale 'ia_FR.UTF-8'

OR

### command

flutter doctor

### exception

> ArgumentError: Invalid argument(s): Invalid locale 'ia_FR.UTF-8'

Saw the error reported on github with no answer to solve it.

complete log output here:

````
Flutter crash report; please file at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.    

## command    

flutter doctor    

## exception    

ArgumentError: Invalid argument(s): Invalid locale 'ia_FR.UTF-8'    

```
#0      Intl._throwLocaleError (package:intl/intl.dart:231)
#1      Intl.verifiedLocale (package:intl/intl.dart:225)
#2      Intl.verifiedLocale (package:intl/intl.dart:210)
#3      new NumberFormat._forPattern (package:intl/src/intl/number_format.dart:486)
#4      new NumberFormat.decimalPattern (package:intl/src/intl/number_format.dart:175)
#5      kMillisecondsFormat (package:flutter_tools/src/base/utils.dart:103)
#6      kMillisecondsFormat (package:flutter_tools/src/base/utils.dart:103)
#7      getElapsedAsMilliseconds (package:flutter_tools/src/base/utils.dart:111)
#8      FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:217)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:194)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:283)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:109)
#12     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:222)
#13     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:109)
#14     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:166)
#15     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:89)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     AppContext._run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:76)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     AppContext.runInZone.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:66)
#18     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
#19     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#20     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1501)
#21     AppContext.runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:65)
#22     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:60)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:44)
<asynchronous suspension>
#24     main (file:///home/dawd/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:16)
#25     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:275)
#26     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:163)
```    

## flutter doctor    

```
[✓] Flutter (on Linux, locale ia_FR.UTF-8, channel master)
    • Flutter at /home/dawd/flutter
    • Framework revision d9fd4d6f49 (6 hours ago), 2018-01-16 15:38:29 +0100
    • Engine revision 05fe72d068
    • Tools Dart version 2.0.0-dev.16.0
    • Engine Dart version 2.0.0-edge.28757928b47b192efcec082c78258102beb03f78    

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/dawd/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: /home/dawd/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)    

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at /home/dawd/android-studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)    

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.3)
    • Flutter plugin version 20.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 173.4127.31    

[✓] Connected devices
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-arm • Android null (API null)    

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well BEFORE cloning the flutter repo, DO :

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

then clone the repo and launch flutter doctor and then you have :

```
[✓] Flutter (on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8, channel alpha)
```